# Como retornar zero, quando JOIN não me traz um valor?

Tags: sql, oracle

estou com um problema nesse SQL,
quando preciso listar uma movimentação mas ainda não foi gravada SMTITMVE  o código. Ai quando cai nesse JOIN  **`AND A.NCODIMVEPI = E.NCODIMVEPI`**.e o JOIN   **`AND  D.NCODIEQEPI = E.NCODIEQEPI`**. Não tenho, retorno. como posso tratar esse problema no SQL?

```
SELECT A.NCODIMVEPI,
       D.CCODIEQEPI,
       A.DDATAMVEPI,
       B.CNOMEFUNCI || ' / CRACHA& ' || B.CCHRMFUNCI || ' / SITUACAO& ' ||
       C.CDESCSITFU NOME
  FROM SMTMVEPI A, SMTFUNCI B, SMTSITFU C,SMTEQEPI  D,SMTITMVE E
 WHERE A.NCODIFUNCI = B.NCODIFUNCI
 AND A.NCODIMVEPI = E.NCODIMVEPI
   AND B.NCODISITFU = C.NCODISITFU
   AND A.DDATAMVEPI BETWEEN &INICIO AND &FIM
   AND B.CNOMEFUNCI || ' / CRACHA& ' || B.CCHRMFUNCI || ' / SITUACAO& ' ||
       C.CDESCSITFU LIKE &FUNCIONARIO || '%'
   AND B.NCODIGOEMPRE = &EMPRESA
  AND  D.NCODIEQEPI = E.NCODIEQEPI
 ORDER BY 2, 3;
```

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada na função `COALESCE`.

Comment: Pesquise por OUTER JOINS e NVL  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2048.htm#OLADM624

Answer (score 1):

Foi resolvido com um **OUTER JOIN**, forcei a trazer os dados mesmo que eles fossem nulos.

```
SELECT A.NCODIMVEPI,
       D.CCODIEQEPI,
       A.DDATAMVEPI,
       B.CNOMEFUNCI || ' / CRACHA& ' || B.CCHRMFUNCI || ' / SITUACAO& ' ||
       C.CDESCSITFU NOME
  FROM SMTMVEPI A, SMTFUNCI B, SMTSITFU C, SMTEQEPI D, SMTITMVE E
 WHERE A.NCODIFUNCI = B.NCODIFUNCI
   AND A.NCODIMVEPI = E.NCODIMVEPI(+)
   AND B.NCODISITFU = C.NCODISITFU
   AND A.DDATAMVEPI BETWEEN &INICIO AND &FIM
   AND B.CNOMEFUNCI || ' / CRACHA& ' || B.CCHRMFUNCI || ' / SITUACAO& ' ||
       C.CDESCSITFU LIKE &FUNCIONARIO || '%'
   AND B.NCODIGOEMPRE = &EMPRESA
   AND D.NCODIEQEPI(+) = E.NCODIEQEPI
 ORDER BY 2, 3;
```